# JDI/JPDA Event Filtering

Tags: java, jpda, jdi

In JDI, there is the API to exclude events from processed events in JVM used by JPDA. This is done using:

1. [`addExclusionFilter(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/request/MethodEntryRequest.html#addClassFilter%28com.sun.jdi.ReferenceType%29) to exclude some pattern; e.g. `addExclusionFilter("java.*")`
2. [`addClassFilter(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/request/MethodEntryRequest.html#addClassExclusionFilter%28java.lang.String%29) to include some pattern; e.g. `addClassFilter("java.util.*")`

Now, I need both. I need to exclude all events coming from `"java.*"` but I need to receive events from `"java.util.Iterator"`.

Also, note that for instance `java.util.Iterator` is an interface implemented by some private class in `java.util.AbstractList`. How do we receive such events to `java.util.Iterator`?

When I used both methods, I actually *do not* receive events any more. Do you have an idea how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do u mean by "I actually receive events any more"?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake by me, question updated.

Comment: For receiving "java.util.Iterator " events addClassFilter("java.util.Iterator") is enough. Your method was not working because you had excluded "java.util.Iterator" already by applying exclusion filter on "java.*".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the addClassFilter method that takes a ReferenceType as an argument, which (unlike the String-arg version) matches any subtype of the given type.  With [jdiscript](https://github.com/jfager/jdiscript) and Java 8, firing on Iterator method calls could look something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JDIScript j = new JDIScript(new VMLauncher(OPTIONS, MAIN).start());

    OnVMStart start = se -> {
        List<ReferenceType> rts = j.vm().classesByName("java.util.Iterator");
        j.methodEntryRequest(me -> {
            println("Your handler here");
        }).addClassFilter(rts.get(0))
          .enable();
    };

    j.run(start);
}
```